# Research differentiability of the function $f(x) = \ln |x^2 - 4x + 3|$. Are there one sided derivatives at points where derivative doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

*Research differentiability of the function $f(x) = \ln |x^2 - 4x + 3|$. Are there one sided derivatives at points where derivative doesn't exist?*

Solving quadratic equation: $x^2 -4x + 3 = 0 \iff x = 1$ or $x = 3 \implies f(x)$ doesn't exist at these points (as well as $f'(x)$).

Taking derivative (I don't know how to take derivative of an absolute function, so gonna split it):
$x \geq 0: f_1'(x) = \frac{2x -4}{x^2-4x+3}$, $x \ne 1$ and $x \ne 3$
$x < 0: f_2'(x) = \frac{2x+4}{x^2 +4x + 3}$,  $x \ne -1$ and $x \ne -3$

Ok, something is wrong. Perhaps, splitting $x$ was a bad idea.

Trying to evaluate one sided limit:
$\lim_{x \to 1-} \frac{\ln (x^2 -4x + 3) - \ln(1^2 - 4\cdot1 + 3)}{x - 1} = \lim_{x \to 1-} \frac{\ln (x^2 -4x + 3) - \ln(0)}{x - 1}$

$\ln 0$ is undefined, so, I guess, left sided derivative doesn't exist. Same will be applied for limit when $x \to 1+$ or $x \to 3+-$.
Unfortunately, I don't know what to do when we are talking about $f_2'(x)$. Should I state that limit is undefined as well when $x \to -1$ or $x \to -3$?

So my questions:

1. How would you show that there are no one sided derivatives at points $x = 1$ and $x = 3$?
2. How would you "research differentiability" of such function at all?

Comment: Your "splitting" idea is in the right track, but you need to choose the points where the absolute value changes sign, i.e. $x=\{1,3\}$. Then, study the behavior of the absolute value in the intervals $A=(-\infty, 1)$, $B=(1,3)$ and $C=(3,\infty)$, and only then you can obtain the (one- or two-sided) derivatives.